# Remove all lines after an 4 digit number from a large number of .txt files

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have files that are split in two blocks, the first half contains the information I need, the second half always starts with a 4 digit number (between 1400 and 1900). I need to delete the second block, hence my question:

How do I delete all lines in a file after (and including) the first 4 digit number?

I believe that should be doable using notepad++ and regular expressions, but I'm new to regex and have no idea how...

I know it's a noob-ish question but nonetheless, help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made any attempts?  Also can you give examples of the lines beyond just the basic description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regex `1(?:[4-8]\d\d|900)(?:.|[\r\n])+\z` will select a text starting with `1400-1900` till the end of a file.